# add frame and remove background colour and grids using seaborn.kdeplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have written a class to plot some data points. I used `seaborn` to make `kernel density` plot and it caused that (1) the frame gets disappeared and I would like a rigid frame and (2) there are grids in the plot with (3)a background colour which I would like to get rid of them. How should it be done? In addition, how could I get star-shape and polygon-shape markers for the scatter plot ?

```
import seaborn
import pandas
import pylab as P
import numpy as np
class PlotLocus(object):
      def __init__(self, colorX, colorY, colorpX, colorpY ,excluded_points,lcolorx1,lcolorx2,lcolory1,lcolory2,correspondence_Matrix):
          self.exarr=excluded_points #scatter points excluded by kde
          self.colorx=colorX
          self.colory=colorY
          self.colorpx=colorpX
          self.colorpy=colorpY
          r=np.arange(self.colorx.shape[0])
          self.arr=np.setxor1d(r,self.exarr)
          self.lx1=lcolorx1 
          self.lx2=lcolorx2 
          self.ly1=lcolory1 
          self.ly2=lcolory2 
          correspondence_indicies = np.where(M > 0.99)
          self.colorx_corr=self.colorx[correspondence_indicies[0]]
          self.colory_corr=self.colory[correspondence_indicies[0]]
          self.colorpx_corr=self.colorpx[correspondence_indicies[1]]
          self.colorpy_corr=self.colorpy[correspondence_indicies[1]]      
      def plot_before_colors(self):
          fig=P.figure(1, figsize=(8,8), dpi=100)
          ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
          X=np.vstack((self.colorx, self.colory)).T
          data = pandas.DataFrame(X, columns=["X", "Y"])
          seaborn.kdeplot(data.X,data.Y,bw='scott',shade=False, cmap="Purples") 
          ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', direction='in', length=6, width=2)
          ax.scatter(self.colorx[self.exarr], self.colory[self.exarr], s=30, c='g', marker='o', edgecolors='k',facecolors='none')
          ax.scatter(self.colorx, self.colory ,marker='.',s=15,color='b')
          ax.scatter(self.colorpx, self.colorpy, s=15, c='r', marker='d', edgecolor='r')
          for i in range(len(self.colorx_corr)):
              ax.annotate("",
                          xy=(self.colorpx_corr[i], self.colorpy_corr[i]), xycoords='data',
                          xytext=(self.colorx_corr[i], self.colory_corr[i]), textcoords='data',
                          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                          connectionstyle="arc3"), 
                          color='0.3'
                          )
          ax.set_xlabel("%s - %s"%(self.lx1,self.lx2), size='medium')
          ax.set_ylabel("%s - %s"%(self.ly1,self.ly2), size='medium')
          ax.set_aspect('auto')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    colorx=np.array([0.4,0.5,-0.3,1.5,0.91,0.66,0.59,-0.11,-0.08,0.12])
    colory=np.array([0.22,-1.15,0.44,0.7,-0.65,-0.21,0.8,-1.1,1.01,0.8])
    colorpx=np.array([0.48,0.45,-0.38,0.5,0.98,0.62,0.77,-0.15,-0.12,0.8])
    colorpx=np.array([0.48,0.45,-0.38,0.5,0.98,0.62,0.77,-0.15,-0.12,0.8,1.8])
    colorpx=np.array([0.48,0.45,-0.38,0.5,0.98,0.62,0.77,-0.15,-0.12,0.8,1.8,2.4])
    colorpy=np.array([0.26,-0.98,-0.1,0.66,-0.7,-0.5,0.84,-0.88,-1.2,0.9,-2.1,1.3])
    lcolorx1='u'
    lcolorx2='i'
    lcolory1='i'
    lcolory2='g'
    M=np.zeros((10,12),float)
    M[1,4]=1
    M[3,5]=1
    M[9,7]=1
    M[0,2]=1
    M[4,10]=1
    p=PlotLocus(colorx,colory,colorpx,colorpy,np.array([2,6,8]),lcolorx1,lcolorx2,lcolory1,lcolory2,M)
    p.plot_before_colors()
    P.show()
```

[image]

Comment: By the way you may want to use the `Purples_d` colormap instead of `Purples`, it will restrict the range a bit more so that the lowest contours don't get washed out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can remove the grey background and white grid by using [`seaborn.set_style(style='white')`](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.set_style.html#seaborn.set_style) at the beginning of your code. This will also add a rigid black border to your plot.

For the markers you can get star shapes using `marker='*'` in the `scatter` call or by using the [matplotlib.markers api](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html).

Below is the plot I get if I add the `seaborn.set_style` call to your code, I've not changed the markers as I don't know which markers you wish to change.

[image: Example Plot]

Comment: I am getting this error:`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_style'`

Comment: what is your `seaborn` version? mine is `0.2.1`.

Comment: fair enough! maybe that is the reason!

Comment: Yeah checking the source code on Github it appears to have been added with 0.3. I'd suggest you upgrade to 0.4 if you can.

Comment: Ffisegydd btw, do you know how I could change the thickness of the contour plot in `seaborn` too?

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer doesn't work with recent seaborn versions.
Use `ax.set_facecolor('white')` instead of `seaborn.set_style(style='white')`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).